# Primefaces calendar - validation before listener

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to trigger bean's method on double click and fill calendar input with current date, before any validation:

```
                <p:calendar id="idInputDueDate" value="#{newMeasureMB.measure.termin}"                      
                        required="true" immediate="true">           

                    <p:ajax event="dblclick"  listener="#{newMeasureMB.terminToCurrent}" 
                        global="false" update="idInputDueDate" immediate="true"/>       

                </p:calendar>
```

Method on backing bean:

```
public void terminToCurrent(){
    measure.setTermin(new Date());      
}
```

It works only when I remove "required=true", otherwise validation always occurs. I am using primefaces 3.3.1

Comment: Don't you need specify particular event in ajax listener method in the  bean as a parameter?

Comment: I don't think so: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxifyAction.jsf

Answer (score 0):

By default `process` attribute of this `p:ajax` is `@this` so your calendar is processed. Add `process="@none"` to no `p:ajax` or remove `immediate="true"` from `p:calendar` so its required validation is not processed (if it is possible according to your use-case).

Comment: I have added `process="@none"`, but now backing bean's method is not called. I also tried with removing `immediate="true"` and again without success

Comment: You removed `immediate="true"` from calendar, not from `p:ajax`?

Comment: Yes, I removed `immediate="true"` from calendar.